# print a page content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page, under a master page. I gave a button for printing the page. But the page will be printed along with the master page contents too. How is it possible to print only the contents of the current page excluding the master page contents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a print.css stylesheet which removes the master page markup contents by id and class. the thing to remember is that although you have defined your common content in a masterpage it will still be presented as complete page and therefore you need to remove those unrequired elements before printing.

Comment: That's impossible without seeing your original HTML markup as well as your current CSS code etc. All I can do is point you in the direction of some example site where they tutor is covering the same topic. Have a read over this tutorial, by the end of reading it you should have a good understanding of how print stylesheets work and how to apply that knowledge to your own scenario. http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

Comment: @Sreejesh: if you find the link useful please score up the comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`print` stylesheet](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml) - in it you can specify that the master page classes are not visible, so they will not get printed.

Comment: isnt there any other solution other than this, like printing only the div ?

Comment: Automatic printing in the browser does not let you select only parts of a page to print. This is the standard solution to your problem.

Comment: @Sreejesh Kumar - There are several ways to do it, using an additional print CSS file with the `media="print"` attribute on the link element is probably the best option.